# How to sum and display time in day-hr-min format

Tags: microsoft-excel, time, date-time

Lets say I want to display O9 in day-hr-min format by adding 08 to I9,J9,K9

[image]

Comment: Please[edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1444936/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far and how it fials to achieve the desired result

Comment: And what would be the result of the formula?

Comment: =(L6+I7)&" days "&(M6+J7)&" hrs "&(N6+K7)&" min"          This is what in O7

Comment: To find O9 I was trying to do =O8+(I9/1+J9/24+K9/1440) but it didn't work because of the format of O8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TIME to get the amount of time:

```
=INT(SUMPRODUCT($I$5:$I6+$L$5:$L6+TIME($J$5:$J6,$K$5:$K6,0)+TIME($M$5:$M6,$N$5:$N6,0))) & " days " & HOUR(SUMPRODUCT($I$5:$I6 + $L$5:$L6  + TIME($J$5:$J6,$K$5:$K6,0) + TIME($M$5:$M6,$N$5:$N6,0))) & " hours " & MINUTE(SUMPRODUCT($I$5:$I6 + $L$5:$L6  + TIME($J$5:$J6,$K$5:$K6,0) + TIME($M$5:$M6,$N$5:$N6,0))) & " minutes"
```

Put that in O6 and copy/drag down.

It creates a day/time value then parses it to get the parts needed.

> `SUMPRODUCT($I$5:$I6+$L$5:$L6+TIME($J$5:$J6,$K$5:$K6,0)+TIME($M$5:$M6,$N$5:$N6,0))`

is the part that sums up all the parts and returns a value that Excel can interpret as a date/time.

Then `INT` returns the days, `HOUR` the hours and `MINUTE` the MINUTES.

Then we concatenate using `&`.

The ranges are anchored on the first line but are relative on the other end to the row in which the formula is placed, thus only summing the lane it is on and those above.

[image]

---

You can also only use the `SUMPRODUCT` part:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($I$5:$I6+$L$5:$L6+TIME($J$5:$J6,$K$5:$K6,0)+TIME($M$5:$M6,$N$5:$N6,0))
```

And format the cells:

```
dd \d\a\y\s hh \h\r\s mm \mi\n\s
```

And it will show what you want and keep the underlying number as a number and not a string:

[image]

Comment: Thank you much, very much appreciate it!!!!

Comment: @user1045372 if this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.